# Enumerated list followed by normal text

Tags: enumerate

What I'm trying is not very conventional maybe, but here it is :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \kant[1]
normal text
    \item \kant[2]
normal text
    \item \kant[3]
normal text
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to have normal text inside an enumerated list. Something like :

```
        1. Item no. one with it's own indented text followed by some non indented text
normal non indented text
normal non indented text
normal non indented text
        2. Item no. two with it's own indented text followed by some non indented text
normal non indented text
normal non indented text
normal non indented text
```

Comment: Is the [indented] itemized text multi-line?  Multi-paragraph?

Comment: Yes, 3 or 4 lines

Comment: ...but a single paragraph always?

Comment: Yes, it's a single paragraph always

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways...first with the created `normalize` environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\newenvironment{normalize}{\leftskip-\leftmargin}{\par}
\begin{document}

\noindent This is my normal left margin.
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \kant[1]
\begin{normalize}
\kant[4]
\end{normalize}
    \item \kant[2]
\begin{normalize}
\kant[4]
\end{normalize}
    \item \kant[3]
\begin{normalize}
\kant[4]
\end{normalize}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, with the `resume` feature provided by the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\noindent This is my normal left margin.
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \kant[1]
\end{enumerate}
\kant[4]
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item \kant[2]
\end{enumerate}
\kant[4]
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item \kant[3]
\end{enumerate}
\kant[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is something strange with the first one : the normal text doesnt follow the same line as the rest of the book. I will try the second one and get back.

Comment: @alfred On second thought, I think the left skip of the 1st method should just be `\leftmargin`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: yes, it works. It gives the same result as sol two now